# This method contains a redundant check of a known non-null value against the constant null

Tags: java, findbugs

```
javac 1.7.0_79
findbugs 3.0.0
```

Hello,

I am using findbugs and I get this reported error:

```
This method contains a redundant check of a known non-null value against the constant null
```

The code in questions is this:

```
 mClientConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
 if(mClientConnection == null) {
    return false;
 }
```

The above code checks that mClientConnection contains a valid reference.

The constructor contains this:

```
public XMPPTCPConnection(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config) {
    super(config);
    this.config = config;
}
```

I am wondering how can I check that the mClientConnection contains a valid reference?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. You have a code that checks that `mClientConnection` contains a valid reference and you want a code to check that it is a valid reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you are getting that message from Findbugs is because a constructor will **never** return `null`. Therefore there is no reason for you to do a null check on `mClientConnection`. If the constructor does fail, the line of code that uses `mClientConnection` will never be called anyways.